# For loop not working while reading multiple json files in a directory

Tags: python

The `error_str` prints out an empty array. I don't think `error_str` is successfully accessed here. The for loop also doesn't iterate more than once as I have multiple json files in my directory.

```py
print("Lemon Squeeze", final_error_code)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'final_error_code' referenced before assignment
```

```py
    def get_error_code_array():
        array_pt_failed_current = []
        # global final_error_code
        for loop in list_of_files:
            # print("This is get error code first loop", loop)
            with open(loop, 'w+') as file:
                # print("This is get error code second loop", loop)
                lines = file.readlines()
                print(lines)
                error_str = json.dumps(lines)
                print("This is get error code of ",error_str)
                for pt_found in re.finditer('PT-', error_str):
                    i = pt_found.end() + 1
                    pt_failed_current = error_str[pt_found.end()] + error_str[i] + error_str[i+1]
                    array_pt_failed_current.append(pt_failed_current)
                    final_error_code = ["PT-"+ls for ls in array_pt_failed_current]
                    # show_error_code_array.append(final_error_code)
        print("Lemon Squeeze", final_error_code)
        return (final_error_code)
                    # return show_error_code_array
    answer = get_error_code_array()
    print(answer)
```

Comment: Can you add an example of input file to your question ? and maybe clarify what you are trying to achieve, as currently it is unclear.

Comment: You are opening the loop files with `w+` mode. In this mode, the file will get overwritten if it exists, or will be created a new one if doesn't exists. You should use another file open mode, such as reading: `rt` for example. Just read about these modes on here: https://tutorial.eyehunts.com/python/python-file-modes-open-write-append-r-r-w-w-x-etc/

Comment: when `list_of_files` is empty then it doesn't run `for`-loop and it doesn't assign value `final_error_code = ...` but later it tries to get value from `final_error_code` to display it. And this gives your error. You have to create this variable with some default value at start of function. ie. `final_error_code = ""`

Answer (score 0):

When `list_of_files` is empty then it doesn't run `for`-loop and it doesn't assign value `final_error_code = ...` but later it tries to get value from `final_error_code` to display it. And this gives your error.

You have to create this variable with some default value at start of function or at start of program if you use `global final_error_code`

```
def get_error_code_array():
    array_pt_failed_current = []

    final_error_code = ""  # <-- default value when `list_of_files` is empty
    
    for loop in list_of_files:
        with open(loop, 'w+') as file:
            lines = file.readlines()
            print(lines)
            error_str = json.dumps(lines)
            print("This is get error code of ",error_str)
            for pt_found in re.finditer('PT-', error_str):
                i = pt_found.end() + 1
                pt_failed_current = error_str[pt_found.end()] + error_str[i] + error_str[i+1]
                array_pt_failed_current.append(pt_failed_current)
                final_error_code = ["PT-"+ls for ls in array_pt_failed_current]
    print("Lemon Squeeze", final_error_code)
    
    return final_error_code

# --- main ---

list_of_files = []                    
answer = get_error_code_array()
print(answer)
```